# PuTTY: Forcibly terminate an SSH session without closing the window

Tags: ssh, putty

Is there a way to forcibly terminate an SSH session in PuTTY, short of closing the PuTTY window?

For example, in OpenSSH, I can use the `~.` escape sequence to kill the connection.

This is useful when the SSH session stops responding for some reason, but I don't want to lose any of my current session-specific settings. In that case, I'd like to kill the session and then use `Restart Session` to reconnect.

Answer (score 1):

You can try sending a break signal by pressing CTRL+Break.

If the connection is an SSH-2 connection and the server supports it, you will have a "Break" option under "Special Commands"

Comment: Sending `Break` doesn't seem to do anything for any of my SSH sessions. It looks like `Break` is more applicable to serial terminals or something.

Comment: The point is to tell PuTTy to close the connection from the client side.  This attempts to tell the server to end the connection, which is not what is being requested here, I don't think.